# How to remove a specific text annotation by clicking on it in Charts?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, annotations

There are multiple text annotations created when the user clicks on separate data points on a chart in Windows Form Application. I want to also provide the functionality of removing a specific annotation when the user clicks(or double clicks!) on it, but I am having a hard time in figuring out how to do this . Here is what I have already tried:

```
private void chart_AnnotationSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
 System.Collections.IList Anno = chart.Annotations;
 foreach(Annotation Item in Anno)
 {
  if(Item.IsSelected)
  {
   chart.Annotations.Remove(Item);
  }
 }
}
```

But nothing is happening. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason the specific annotation was not being removed on clicking ; the flag for selecting the annotation had to be set because it is `false` by default. Added the statement `annotation.AllowSelecting = true;` and the specific annotation is now being removed upon clicking.

Answer (score 1):

After removing the item try to invalidate the chart by:

```cs
chart.Invalidate();
```

Also, make sure to stop looping while you invalidate items, so you might need to break the loop, or first do a foreach to remove all the items and eventually invalidate once the chart.